# I just bought the wrong album on iTunes. How do I give it back?

Tags: itunes

I just bought the wrong album on iTunes. How do I give it back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/

Contact customer support via e-mail and hopefully you can get a refund.

Comment: I have done this before and they are usually pretty helpful, as long as you do it straight away.

Answer (score 6):

You can dispute the purchase within iTunes.

- Go to iTunes Store, view your Account (login if needed).
- Find and click on Purchase History.
- Click on the arrow next to the purchase to see the details
- Click on the report a Problem Button
- Click on the Report a Problem link next to the Playlist/Album in question.
- Select the Problem from the dropdown ( I inadvertently purchased this playlist)
- Fill in any comments.
- Hit Submit

This will send the request off to Apple Customer Support and they should credit you back. I have not done this myself, but a co-worker has and said it worked fine. They will likely flag your account though if this becomes a common thing.

Answer (score -1):

In the United States, call 800-692-7753 (1-800-myapple) and when asked what you need, say "agent". Repeat "agent" until you get a human. You can then start the refund process.

Comment: You can't just assume people live in usa...